# Working with multiple calendars

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have multiple calendars. How would I amend this query to specify which `calendar` I want the `events` for? Also, can I say, all calendars.

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/Calendar/Events`

I see that each calendar has a unique "id", though that only differs by one character. s,t,u,v,w,x curiously.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You use the [`/calendars`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendars) endpoint to get the list of calendars:

```http
GET /me/calendars
```

You then use the `id` that gets returned to select the calendar you want to return events from:

```http
GET /me/calendars/{id}/events
```

You most likely want [`/calendarView`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview) rather than [`/events`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_events) resource however. A `calendarView` provides the same results you would normally see in the client's calendar  (i.e. Outlook, OWA).

The `/events` returns lower level data and using this endpoint for Read operations requires understanding how Series Master`, Occurrence, and Exception resources work in Exchange. The`calendarView` simplifies things but providing a view of a rendered view of a given date range:

```http
GET /me/calendars/{id}/calendarView?startDateTime={dateTime}&endDateTime={dateTime}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Just what I wanted.